# How to execute two asynchronous function in sequence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization

How to make asynchronous Javascript function execute in sequence

```
socket_connection.on('request', function (obj) {
    process(obj);
});
function process(obj){
    readfile(function(content){ //async
        //read content
        //modify content
        writefile(content, function(){ //async
            //write content
        });
    });
}
```

This results in sequence:

```
read content
read content
modify content
modify content
write content
write content
```

How can I enforce:

```
read content
modify content
write content
read content
modify content
write content
```

Comment: @squint - spot on. actually I want to handle one type of request - one at a time.

Comment: actually this in chrome plugin. uses async storage api  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Then I'm going to delete all my comments. Please provide relevant detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is known as blocking. In this case you want to block the second or consecutive request until the first request completes.

My honest opinion - NodeJS is not a suitable platform if you want to block the call. NodeJS will not be able to perform as freely as it should be.

That being said you can do something similar to -

```
var isExecuting = false;
socket_connection.on('request', function (obj) {
    // in other languages you could have done something similar to 
    // while(isExecuting); 
    // but that may not work here.
    var intrvl = setInterval(function(){
        if(!isExecuting){
            clearInterval(intrvl); 
            isExecuting=true; 
            process(obj);  
        }
    },0); // if necessary put some number greater than 0

});
function process(obj){
    readfile(function(content){ //async
        //read content
        //modify content
        writefile(content, function(){ //async
            //write content
          isExecuting = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Split your functions and chain them with Promise**

You're lucky enough. ECMAScript6 Promise is designed to solve your problem very neatly. From your original code, given you have these small functions to invoke in sequence within `process()` function.

```
function readfile(callback){
     ....
     callback(content);
}

function writefile(content,callback){
     ...
     callback();
}
```

You can *promisify* them and invoke them in sequence.

```
function process(obj){
    Promise.resolve(obj){
        readfile(done);
    })
    .then(function(content){
        // content read from "readfile" is passed through here as content
        return new Promise(function(done,reject){
            // Make any modification to "content" as you want here
            // ...
            writefile(done);
        });              
    })
    .then(function(){
         // Finish write file! do something
    });
}
```

From the code above, your functions are invoked in sequence which is controlled by Promise flow. The call flow will look like this:

> process() ⟶ readfile() ⟶ done is called when readfile finishes 
>   ⟶ then() ⟶ writefile() ⟶ done is called when writefile finishes ⟶ then() ⟶ ...